# Where can I see a gallery of standard library WPF controls?

Tags: c#, wpf

Where can I see a gallery of WPF controls? There must be at least thirty  in the standard library, I'd like to see what they all look like / do.

Google autocomplete tells me this is a very popular search, but I can't find squat!

For comparison, here is a gallery of [GTK widgets](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/ch03.html) from GNOME documentation.

Comment: If you use Blend many of the controls have a small icon and description from the controls toolbar [as seen here](http://www.thedatafarm.com/blog/content/binary/step6.png)

Comment: Will why do you say "this question will likely solicit debate, arguments, polling, or extended discussion". I just want a hyperlink to some documentation.

Comment: Try http://www.tutorialspoint.com/wpf/wpf_controls.htm

Answer (score 4):

there are descriptions / screenshots for many wpf controls on this website: 
http://www.wpftutorial.net/Controls.html

Comment: Also a good resource is http://www.tutorialspoint.com/wpf/wpf_controls.htm

Answer (score 0):

The point is that WPF controls are extensibly restylable, so they don't have to look the same as they were originally designed. For example its quite easy to build a TreeView out of a ListBox, or to change a TextBox so it auto suggests and looks more like a Combo Box.

Also, the controls don't all intrinsically have style either. An ItemsControl provides most of the functionality of a ListBox, but looks identical. In fact a StackPanel (Orientation=Vertical) would also look exactly the same (for a small number of items) and a ScrollViewer would look the same for a large number of items.

I'm honestly not trying to be awkard, just simply pointing out that often a Control defines functionality and a Style defines the look.

Comment: That's irrelevant though, any good UI will have a control function the way it looks. The gallery could consist of napkin drawings for all I care, I just want to know the name of the component I'm looking for.